# How to implement Dynamic Picker in react native with multiple picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker

I need to implement dynamic picker which will be implemented when the user selects any value from the parent picker, based on that we will display one or many child pickers.
In react native selectedValue only receive object and I need to set it inside map loop where on changing its value should be dynamically changed. How can I implement this.
my code is:

```
res.data.map((s, i) => {
 return (
  <Picker
   key={i}
   selectedValue={}//want to set to selected value
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {console.log('here')}}>
   s.dropdown.map((v, j) => {
    return (<Picker.Item key={j} value={v.Part.id} label={v.Part.Name} />)
   });
  </Picker>
 );
});
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? if yes can you please solve my question its important for me . any help would be appreciated
[my question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446229/how-to-show-selected-item-for-each-picker-component-with-api-in-react-native)