# How to show selected item for each Picker component with API in React-native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, api, picker

> I need to show the selected item in Picker.
> what I need to do is to show Picker with API and when I select each
> of the item inside of picker it get selected and should be shown just
> like below 2nd picture

[my code in expo for live changes](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/multiple-picker-value)

[image: first picture showing result]
[image: after selected each of the item]

> I showed the expected behaviour in my code in above pictures.
> any help would be appreciated